Please let the mods allow a user more replies in a mod message without responding
Currently, users are only allowed 1 reply to mod messages, and there is no warning of this. I would imagine that users may reply to a mod message with something that is both not disruptive/rude/etc. and also does not necessitate a reply. I would imagine that it would be useful if the mods had the ability to grant the user the ability to send more mod messages (or maybe even completely remove the limit for a specific user). Could this be done?

I'm good with explicitly letting a user know they can reply once. I'm not sure what the utility of allowing for more replies without prompting is.
We use mod messages for basically 3 reasons:

Suspensions. Bad things are done. We would like to communicate why this is bad and the consequences. Unless there's an actual misunderstanding, there's rarely a reason to have an extended conversation.

We're trying to inform a user of something, to avoid them doing it in the future and getting suspended.

There's complicated issues that need a paper trail, and privacy. These could be things that are very serious.


The four places where I see that a mod message would need a reply are:

where there's an attempt at cleanup/vandalism of a user's own posts where the suspension is used as a way to stop further damage. A reply here is an acknowledgement that the message is received.

a user is informed not to do something (but not suspended).

a user's username is reset but we're willing to help them change it back. I've literally never gotten a reply to these offers.

we're using a moderator message to convey details of a private matter to a user. I can probably count the number of times I've had to do a back and forth over my time as a moderator on one hand.


Taking all this into account. The mod messaging system is not designed as a platform for conversation, discussion, or dialog. It's meant to be a way to push information to a specific user for the purposes of maintaining the site.
As a moderator and a regular user, I don't see the utility of this. If there was a need for me to talk to my users (in private!), we have chat. If we need a public discussion, we have meta, and if there's a need for oversight/review, we have the contact page.
I think that this is a very longwinded way of me asking - what problem does it solve for moderators and users? I can't think of any scenario where I'd need to turn this on to provide an experience for my users.

No. This is a terrible idea.
If moderators wanted more replies, they are perfectly capable of asking for replies, or inviting the user to a private chat room for more thorough conversation.
But in the vast majority of cases, no reply is required or desired. The user is being informed of something, most likely that their prior behaviours are bordering on unacceptable or disallowed, and must now act on that information,  not speak on it. Moderators can see whether the message has been read or not, so even a "thanks, got it" serves no purpose.
At best, a warning that only one reply is allowed would be sensible,  for the cases where the user is unfamiliar with the system and responds rashly before raising a point of query, but even then, it is on the user to make their next action  a reasonable and coherent choice.
This is a solution looming for a problem, where, at best, the problem has far better solutions either already available or more easily implemented and far less susceptible to abuse and defeating the purpose of moderator messages.

I don’t think it is a good idea to let users be allowed to write more than 1 reply to mod messages. Moderators do not have much time to read all of your replies, if you write too many replies, that is an extra job for moderators.
If some users don’t want to listen to what the moderators’ message, and write many bad replies to the moderators, I think that is quite annoying to moderators, right?
So, I think 1 reply is enough, and the reply should be easy enough to let the moderators understand what you have written.
Just my experience: Usually, the moderators messages are clear enough and explained clearly. There’s not much to argue about with the moderators.
I usually won’t write a reply like “Thank you.” or “I understand that.” to the moderators as those messages are unnecessary to them.
You only need to write the important points (to clarify clearly if there are some mistakes) if you really want to send a reply message to the moderators.

Yes. This is why it would only be used in cases where a user accidently "wastes" their reply or there is some other reason why a second reply seems necessary.

Nope, I think 1 reply is enough, at least for me.

Can you seriously not imagine any situation where it might make sense for the mods to have a "manual override" button allowing a second reply?

I’m not sure what you mean “manual override” here.

Allowing mods to "override" the 1 message limit for a specific case.

@Starship that is trivially easy: just have the mod who wants to "override" send another message
